# Firebase crashlytics not registering all crashes

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I have implemented firebase crashlytics in my unity game to receive the reports of the crashes and It is working half-fuel. It is reporting some crashes but for some reason,It is not reporting all crashes. I have numerous report from users crashing at the same part of the game but I am unable to reproduce the problem or find it in the crashlytics report.

Is anything more that I can do in order to receive all of the crashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of crashes that Crashlytics will track: fatal and non-fatal. For the most part, crashes on iOS and Android are fatal crashes (the entire app/game crashed and the user is looking at their phone's home screen). On Unity, Crashlytics actually registers a [LogCallback](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html) and reports uncaught exceptions. Typically these do not fully crash your game, but still indicate bad and crashy behaviour. I've written a [two](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/crashlytics-and-unity-part-1-ca0598862918?source=friends_link&sk=d8dc15756699abf2b18bd2b7160c469b) [part](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/crashlytics-and-unity-part-2-498dce6d36ba?source=friends_link&sk=6b0adaa2522f3cbdfca1637f81361f2e) series on what different crashes look like there.

So the first (easy) answer is to make sure you're showing "non fatal" crashes.

The second answer is a little more difficult. A crash *may* occur in native code (I've typically forced a stack overflow to simulate this or run Unity out of memory, but there's a [ForceCrash](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Diagnostics.Utils.ForceCrash.html) call I've seen developers using recently). How this gets reported gets a little hairy, partially because [C++ is not officially supported by Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup#available-libraries).

In my experience, these tend to show up as fatal crashes but poorly labelled. On iOS, they appear symbolicated but tend to select the wrong part of the stack frame to display. On Android I tend to see just a non-symbolicated crashed report (something that looks like it could be run through [ndk-stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack)).

If you don't see your crash when you're looking at non-fatal crashes, try looking at just fatal crashes and seeing if you see anything that looks like a raw crash log. Technically Crashlytics can symbolicate native symbols on [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports), and the team is [aware that there are issues](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/745). If this represents your experience, I'd recommend filing an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) or with [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) to see if there either is an issue with your setup or if this is another use case that needs to get tracked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can see my non-fatal crashes so this is not the problem. The problem comes with the fatal crashes. I have a video from a user that get the fatal crash but the firebase crashlytics shows 100% free crash users on that day. So the problem is that I am not getting all the fatal crashes. For the symbols there is no problem since I can resolve them in unity. Is anyway that I am not receiving all the fatal crashes?

Comment: In this case, it sounds like a bug in Crashlytics, I'd suggest following one of the support links I listed. Going to Firebase Support directly, someone might be able to look at your project and see if there's a misconfiguration (if necessary). Going to GitHub an engineer might see it faster but if there's something project-specific there's less they can do to help.